# removing smart quotes and other non code characters

Tags: php

I've got a line of code that I need to run against my WordPress site but it contains a number of 'illegal' characters. I can catch the smart quotes, but hesitant to run it for fear it might do some serious - and permanent - damage!

```
function maybe_unserialize( $original ) {
    if ( is_serialized( $original ) ) // don’t attempt to unserialize data that wasn’t serialized going in
    {
        $original = preg_replace(‘!s:(\d+):”(.*?)”;!se’, “‘s:’.strlen(‘$2′).’:\”$2\”;'”, $original);
        return @unserialize( $original );
    }
    return $original;
}
```

in particular, I don't know about `′` and `'` on the 4th line.

Is there somewhere I can go to strip out these chars and replace them?

Comment: it seems you have copy-pasted some code from a 3rd party without actually understanding *what it does*. while you shouldn't ever do this, the best way to solve your problem would be to go back to that 3rd party and get the code again, without any front-end-formatting - which is what probably happened here.

Answer (score 0):

If you are running a Unix-like system, I recommend using the `sed` command. Suppose the root of the project is `$PROJECT_DIR`, and the file system layout is:

```
$PROJECT_DIR
└── A
    ├── 1.php
    └── B
        └── 2.php
```

Then you can run the following command:

```
find "$PROJECT_DIR" -type f -name '*.php' -exec sed -i.backup \
  -e "s/‘/'/g; s/”/\"/g; s/“/\"/g; s/’/'/g; s/′/'/g" {} \+
```

The command replaces the "smart" quotes with the ASCII single and double quotes in-place. Old files are saved with `.backup` prefix:

```
$PROJECT_DIR
└── A
    ├── 1.php
    ├── 1.php.backup
    └── B
        ├── 2.php
        └── 2.php.backup
```

Then you will be able to rollback the changes with a `find` command:

```
find "$PROJECT_DIR" -type f -name '*.php.backup' \
  -exec bash -c 'mv -f "$0" "${0%.backup}"' {} \;
```

And the following command verifies PHP syntax for all `*.php` files in the tree:

```
find "$PROJECT_DIR" -type f -name '*.php' -exec php -l {}  \;
```

*Sample Output*

```
No syntax errors detected in ./A/1.php
No syntax errors detected in ./A/B/2.php
```